# asterisk изоляция sip клиентов

Tags: asterisk

можно ли как-то изолировать sip клиентов между собой?

например, есть две группы sip-клиентов, которые могут звонить через внешние транки и между собой, но не могут звонить другой группе клиентов.

как можно подобное организовать на одном астериск, что бы не плодить виртуалки

Answer (score 3):

Можно привязать sip клиентов к разным контекстам и настроить маршрутизацию. Базовую информацию про контексты можно взять [тут](http://asterisk.ru/knowledgebase/Asterisk%20Dialplan%20Introduction).

Условный пример (группа 100-199 и группа 200-299):

```
sip.conf

[100]
context=branch1
...
[101]
context=branch1
...
[200]
context=branch2
...
[201]
context=branch2
...

extensions.conf

[branch1]
exten => _1XX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
exten => _8XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/operator/${EXTEN})

[branch2]
exten => _2XX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
exten => _8XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/operator/${EXTEN})
```